# Why did Nikki Haley continue in the race for Republican nomination for so long?

Tags: united-states, republican-party, primaries, republican-primary

In the ongoing race to select the Republican Party nominee, Nikki Haley has lost every primary and caucus but one. That was the District of Columbia Republican primary, which she won with 62% of the vote. However, the District of Columbia primary has historically been an outlier due to the low number of Republican voters in the district. In any case, her chances of securing the nomination are slim to none.

So what did she hope to gain by staying in the contest for so long? Normal answers would be "a place as vice president on the ticket" or "greater exposure in preparation for a future presidential run," but neither seems convincing here. The first because the longer she stays in the contest, the more she irritates Trump, and the second because, given the Republican Party's attachment to Trump, she is not exactly endearing herself to them.

Comment: https://youtu.be/N_N16ojyYEA?t=87

Comment: this question could have waited till tomorrow.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it won't age at all well.

Comment: So the verdict is out, she just dropped out of the race.

Comment: Edit suggestion to reopen this question: Why DID Nikki Haley continue in the race for Republican nomination for so long?

Comment: Haley also won the Vermont primary.

Comment: FWIW, six weeks is one of the shortest time periods for an open Presidential nomination to be resolved in U.S. history.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason can be summed up simply: to accumulate political capital.

Although we may not know it, there are many presidential candidates. They have never had a splashy exploit and have not been exposed by mainstream media, which is why they cannot compete. Nikki Haley calls herself anti-Trump and threatens to fight Trump to the bitter end, which is a pretty good stunt. Although Nikki Haley has failed miserably in almost every encounter with Trump, there is no doubt that she has been known across the country and even the world. In the 2028 presidential election, Nikki Haley's reappearance will undoubtedly benefit from the grand campaign in 2024. A candidate who appears in front of the mainstream media is much better in a formal competition than one who is unknown.

Comment: Not to say this is necessarily wrong and it certainly speaks to the, quite popular, cynicism about all politicians.  However, it also conveniently ignores the fact that - in the US, with its renewal-via-primaries churn - ex-POTUS candidates often slip out of sight entirely or get identified with their failure - Dukakis' tank/ Dean's scream - making them into rather deflated political figures very quickly.  If Trump doesn't implode his base somehow, all the more true of someone who dared defy the [God Emperor](https://intapi.sciendo.com/pdf/10.2478/perc-2021-0017)

Answer (score 12):

She's said she's catering to Americans in general, since polls repeatedly show that most Americans are dismayed at the prospect of another Biden vs. Trump matchup.

> Nikki Haley has suggested a “majority of Americans” do not want Donald Trump or Joe Biden as president.
>
> Speaking to NewsNation on Tuesday 20 February, the Republican hopeful said her campaign is giving voters “a choice”.
>
> “This is about the fact that the majority of Americans dislike both candidates, 70 per cent of Americans say they don’t want a Trump v Biden rematch,” Ms Haley said.
>
> “We are giving them a choice.”

[Source](https://www.independent.co.uk/tv/news/biden-trump-election-nikki-haley-b2499906.html)

Comment: The only answer that actually cites Haley.

Answer (score 10):

I would think she was clinging on in the hopes that Mr Trump would somehow be unable to participate in the election, due to the many judiciary proceedings against him.

And if Mr Trump were somehow disqualified, barred, or unable to participate, then the RNC would need an alternative candidate, and depending on when exactly that happens, they may have to fall back on the next primary candidate with the most votes / still in the running.

It was a pretty long shot, and, of course, yesterday's US Supreme Court decision reduced strongly the chances of this happening, but there are quite a few other lawsuits in progress which could still be a problem.

#### Edit

She has now dropped out of the race.

Answer (score 7):

Donald Trump is 77. [There is a ~5% probability he will die before the election](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/STATS/table4c6.html#fn1). She might as well be there.

Comment: That's not how statistics work.

Comment: @gerrit can you elaborate?  the table in question cites a 5% chance of *death within a year for a 77 year old*.  seems to match this well enough.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecological_fallacy Rich people tend to live longer, for starters, etc. Remember  Trump's mega-special treatment for Covid etc.? https://time.com/5896274/trump-covid-19-treatments/

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat that's really, really, unspecific as to why a table entry giving a 5% chance of dying within a year for a 77 year old is somehow missing the point here.  Are you saying a 77 year old doesn't carry about that level of risk in 1 year, *on average*?  because, well that sounds not that far off.  That article is chock full of warnings and its relationship to a carefully calculated actuarial table is unclear.  As you get older, the wealth boost gets less - you won't live to 100 just because you are a billionaire.

Comment: Economist covered that [2-3 months back](https://www.economist.com/science-and-technology/2024/01/09/heart-attacks-strokes-dementia-can-biden-and-trump-beat-the-odds) : *Today his [Mr Biden’s] chances of surviving through a second term in office are close to 75% (about 10% better survival than for an average man his age). Similar, although slightly less favourable survival prospects are present for Trump.”*  And, as they also put it, though Biden looked feeble for falling off his bike, he looked quite fit for being on it in the first place.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: fair enough, but that takes into account far more factors, e.g. "Mr Trump’s brothers died at the ages of 42 and 71 and his father developed Alzheimer’s." And Fred lived to 93 actually.

Comment: One of Trump's bros died of alcoholism tho.  Whatever the "genius"s faults that's not one of them - his 3am tweets are from a sober person.  if Gerrit meant to talk about the wealth effect, fine, mention that directly, not some dismissive "that's not how stats work".

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: so, you're arguing that the analysis is bad? If we're at it, Fred Jr. was also disinherited earlier on, so he wasn't even rich when he died.

Comment: 5% for one thing is going to be slightly off as there are 8 months till Nov.  And I don't think Haley did it just for that reason, her own deadline was predictably Super Tuesday.  Not Nov.  Also her strategy would have been better as a sycophant to pick votes if it happened:   Ramaswamy.  But "stats are hard but I won't explain why you're wrong" is not being enlightening in the least.  We know stats are hard, don't make people even more scared of thinking about them.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica That's a statistical property for an entire population cohort.  That doesn't mean any particular individual has a 5% chance of dying, because there are dozens of other factors impacting this probability.

Comment: While that could be true in many fields, in this case, at that age, "dozens of other factors" are quite likely to be highly dominated by the age factor, absent a known illness for an individual, which would heighten that probability.  If you can provide some actual backing for your claim of high variability, relevant to this particular age group, not a generic handwavium about stats in general, fine.  Otherwise, I certainly don't buy it.

Comment: This discussion has been going on too long anyway, so let me add a bit to it: There's a notable difference between 77 year olds who are still mobile, no cancer, no upcoming operation, no long term disease, and the average state of the those 5% among the 77 year olds who die within half a year. But even if Trump is 5 times less likely to perish than this answer suggests, Haley taking a 1% chance of winning the nomination doesn't seem unreasonable, so the answer still holds.

Answer (score 1):

### To give voters a choice

An “election” with only one candidate isn't very fun.  *Someone* had to be the penultimate candidate standing, and with Asa Hutchinson, Vivek Ramaswamy, and Ron DeSantis dropping out of the race early in the primary season, Nikki Haley kind of became the last non-Trump candidate by default.  [Haley herself called this a “duty”.](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2024/feb/25/nikki-haley-trump-south-carolina-republican-primary)

> I said earlier this week that no matter what happens in South Carolina, I would continue to run for president. I’m a woman of my word...In the next 10 days, another 21 states and territories will speak. They have the right to a real choice, not a Soviet-style election with only one candidate. And I have a duty to give them that choice.

There is a segment of Republican voters who are not fully aligned with Trump or his leadership style, and Haley provided an alternative for them to vote for.  Unfortunately for Haley, this segment turned out not to be as large as she had previously thought.

### To maintain visibility

By choosing to stay in the race, Haley continued to garner attention from the media and from the Republican party leadership.  She may have been using her presidential campaign as an opportunity to expand her network of supporters or to gain experience for some future political endeavor.